# update table with ajax and spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I try to refresh a table in my jsp page.
My table load a list with all  possible result.
But after a search i want update my table just with result of search.

My table:

```
<table id="table_grid">
[...]
<c:forEach items="${cardlist}" var="card" >
<tr>
    <td>${card.name}</td>
    [...]
</tr>
</c:forEach>            
[...]
</table>
```

My search form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="searchform" id="formSearch" action="#">
<form:select path="critere" >
  <option value="1">name</option> 
  [...]
</form:select>
<form:input type="text" path="value"/>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchAjax()"/>
```

My ajax call:

```
function searchAjax() {
$.ajax({
    url : 'searchlostcard',
    type: 'POST',
    data:$('#formSearch').serialize(),
    success : function(responce) {   

        /* what  i have to put here to updte my table <table id="table_grid"> */

    },      
    error : function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

}

i want my table to be updated by this list `listlostcard` of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
public  @ResponseBody
void searchlostcard(@ModelAttribute(value="searchform") SearchForm searchForm) {    

List<Lostcard> listlostcard = lostcardRepository.findByNom(searchForm.getValue());

/*How to update list cardlist here*/
}
```

i try this `model.put("cardlist", listlostcard);` and in ajax call`success : function(responce) { $('#table_grid').update(); }` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use @ResponseBody you probably want to send a serialized String in JSON or XML representing the List of Lost card.

So add jackson to your classpaht to have a JSON serializer

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

in the controller return your list

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchlostcard") 
public  @ResponseBody
void searchlostcard(@ModelAttribute(value="searchform") SearchForm searchForm) {    

List<Lostcard> listlostcard = lostcardRepository.findByNom(searchForm.getValue());

return listlostcard ;
}
```

your JS function will look like this :

```
function searchAjax() {
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    url : 'searchlostcard',
    headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    data:$('#formSearch').serialize(),
    success : function(responce) {   

        /* what  i have to put here to updte my table <table id="table_grid"> */
        $.each( responce,function(key, card) {
            var htmlrow ="<tr><td>" + card.name + "</td></tr>";         
            $('#table_grid').append(htmlrow);
        }

    },      
    error : function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand this `$.each( responce,function(key, card)` where come from this `function(key, card)` ?

Comment: $.each is a jquery function that will iterate an array for each element of the array the function is called.
http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Card is simply an element of the array, because responce contains an array of Lostcard. $.each will iterate the array and call the function as many times as there is Lostcard in it.

Comment: `void` should be `List<Lostcard>` in your controller.